# Javascript - Sum of an array equals NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I am calculating the top 4 largest numbers of my array with this:

```
let topArr = data.map(e => Number(e.replace(/(,\s*)+/g, '').trim()))
    .sort((a, b) => {
        return b - a
    })
    .slice(0, 4)
    .map((item) => {
        return String(item).replace(/(.)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,')
    });

console.log // Array(4) [ "195,918", "171,749", "167,076", "116,486" ]
```

I am now attempting to calculate the sum of those 4 numbers in an array using `.reduce` in my attempt but I am getting a return of NaN here is my code:

```
let sum = topArr.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
}, 0);
```

I also did not that these numbers being were turned were a string of numbers so attempted to convert those into integers with `let sumArr = topArr.map(Number);` which is also returning NaN. I am expecting a total sum outcome for the 4 numbers in my array which equals to `651,229`

Comment: Commas are not allowed in JavaScript numbers.

Comment: The first expression removes the commas and converts the values to numbers before doing the mathematics, the second doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commas aren't in JavaScript numbers - plus, at the end of `topArr`'s function chain, you convert everything back to a string. To best preserve your existing code, I've simply added your comma string replacement regex to the `reduce`:

```js
const data = ["195,918", "171,749", "167,076", "116,486"]

let topArr = data.map(e => Number(e.replace(/(,\s*)+/g, '').trim()))
  .sort((a, b) => {
    return b - a
  })
  .slice(0, 4)
  .map((item) => {
    return String(item).replace(/(.)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,')

  });

let sum = topArr.reduce((a, b) => a + Number(b.replace(/(,\s*)+/g, '').trim()), 0);

console.log(topArr);
console.log(sum);
```

However, this solution is more efficient, as it removes the reconversion to a string at the end of `topArr`:

```js
const data = ["195,918", "171,749", "167,076", "116,486"]

let topArr = data.map(e => Number(e.replace(/(,\s*)+/g, '').trim()))
  .sort((a, b) => {
    return b - a
  });

let sum = topArr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(topArr);
console.log(sum);
```

As you can see, they both produce the same (correct) output.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this as follows:

```js
const numbers = [100, 1274, 55, 83, 21, 8, 1000, 62]
const sortedNumbers = numbers.sort((a, b) => b - a)
const sum = sortedNumbers.slice(0, 4).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
console.log(sum)
```

We first sort your number array in descending order.  We then know that the first four array elements are the four largest numbers, thus we perform our reduce operation on `numbers.slice(0, 4)`.

If the list consists of strings rather than integers, you can modify the code as such:

```js
const numbers = ["100", "1,274", "55", "83", "21", "8", "1000", "62"]
intNumbers = []
numbers.forEach((n) => intNumbers.push(parseInt(n.replace(/,/g, ""))))
const sortedNumbers = intNumbers.sort((a, b) => b - a)
const sum = sortedNumbers.slice(0, 4).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: The sum of an array of positive integers containing a number like "1,274" should be more than 300. `parseInt("1,274")` returns `1`. :-o

Comment: You're right parseInt was not properly converting the strings with commas.  Fixed.